# Change Entity Framework Context Connection String Based On Logged in User

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've been struggling with this one for quite some time and have been unable to find a good solution.  I'm using the code first method, and this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

First, when a user logs into the application, I authenticate him and retrieve his connection string from a company table in a membership database.

Next, I want to use this connection string for the dbcontext.  Each company has it's own database with the same structure.

Here are two things I'd like to avoid:

1. I don't want to pass the connection string to the context constructor because this is an existing app and there are several calls.
2. I don't want to use session because the library is shared with a windows service app that loops through the connections in the company table to perform data imports.

Any suggestions?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: #1 is mute... ctrl-f

Comment: One helpful piece of advice that I can offer you is to *NOT* store connection string data in the database unencrypted. If your DB that holds the connection strings gets compromised, then the user will acquire all of your connection strings, hence giving him access to all of your DBs.

Comment: I get what you are saying about the first point, however it isn't a simple find throughout the project.  There are several chained calls within the project.  I don't want to find all of the references, find all of the calling references, etc.  I would need to pass the connection string from constructor to constructor...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Keyvan.  That field is encrypted with along with the user password field.